# Why Facebook Robyn Algorithm needs only unique dates?

Tags: regression, data-analysis

My team and I have been exploring the Robyn algorithm to do Market Mix Modeling on my dataset. The dataset is monthly level data of the promotional activity for each customer. In this case the data looks like this-

```
|Id         |Date    |Revenue|Channels…|
|-----------|--------|-------|---------|
|Customer 1 |Jan-2021|       |         |        
|   …..     |        |       |         |  
|Customer 1 |Dec-2021|       |         |
|Customer 2 |Feb-2021|       |         |
|   …..     |        |       |         |
|Customer 2 |Dec-2021|       |         |
```

In this way we have over 1000 customers and their monthly data of the channel activity. We have been able to create models using linear regression to get the impact of each channel. Now when we tried to run this data on Robyn we get a **duplicate date error**, so does this mean we have to run Robyn algorithm for each customer separately? Then we will have only 12 data points for the model and getting daily or weekly is also not possible for us. Is there anyway to run this kind of data on Robyn? Also why does Robyn restrict us to use unique dates even though it uses ridge regression internally which would not be affected by dates, isn’t having more datapoints better?

[About Robyn](https://facebookexperimental.github.io/Robyn/docs/analysts-guide-to-MMM/)

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving this **duplicate date error** because unfortunately, Robyn does not treat panel datasets properly at the moment.  You can aggregate the different customer segments in your datasets and run the modeling at a total level which Robyn supports.